# NiFi - How to send GET request with JSON via InvokeHTTP processor?

Tags: json, get, apache-nifi

I need to send the following GET request with JSON to https://www.example.com/api/

```
GET /path/to/data
{
 "abcd": [
   "a1",
   "a2"
   ]
}
```

Which is encoded in URL in such a way:
https://www.example.com/api/path/to/data?json=%8B%0B%+.....

I tried to accomplish this request via these two NiFi flows:

1. GenerateFlowFile -> ReplaceText -> UpdateAttribute -> InvokeHTTP -> PutFile
2. GenerateFlowFile -> UpdateAtribute -> AttributeToJSON -> InvokeHTTP -> PutFile

However, I fail to send the JSON with the request. Could you please give me a hint on how to configure these processors or suggest a different NiFi flow? (I also need to use Basic Authentication, that's the reason why I use InvokeHTTP processor)

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GetHTTP processor for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't. Since GET request with body is not popular and many avoid that(for stupid reasons) - GET with body is not supported by many frameworks(NiFi amongst them.)

So neither `GetHTTP`(which any way wouldn't help you since it doesn't accept incoming relationships) nor `InvokeHTTP` would help you. You'll probably be able to do this using `ExecuteScript` developing something of your own.